# How to allocate port range (5000 to 5050) for particular application?

Tags: windows

I have installed Supportworks application on Windows server 2012 R2. The application is not working as application required ports utilized by windows services (wininit.exe, lsass.exe, svchost.exe). Is there any potion to free that port range (5000 to 5050) for application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reserve a TCP port in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254330/reserve-a-tcp-port-in-windows)

Comment: @Richard yes, for sure this is